# Python(3.6): program was not found in path

Tags: python-3.x, windows, path

On Windows 10 (PyCharm IDE), i tried import the pythone-nmap module to get PortScenner.
The code i wrote:

```
import nmap
ns = nmap.PortScanner()
a = ns.nmap_version()
print(a)
```

Afterward, i got the following error:

> C:\Users\Mind1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
>   C:/Users/Mind1/PycharmProjects/testNmap/main.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/Mind1/PycharmProjects/testNmap/main.py", line 2, in
>
> ns = nmap.PortScanner()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Mind1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nmap\nmap.py",
>   line 131, in **init**
>
> os.getenv('PATH')
>
> nmap.nmap.PortScannerError: 'nmap program was not found in path.
>
> PATH is : C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Mind1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nmap\nmap.py;C:\tizen-studio\tools\ide\bin;C:\Users\Mind1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Mind1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\Mind1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft VS
>   Code\bin;C:\Programing\SQLite3;C:\Users\Mind1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program
>   Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
>   2019.2.3\bin;;C:\Users\Mind1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nmap\nmap.py;'

My questions are:
Why isn't it found in the path, when it is there at the end of the path?
Why are there 2 semi-colon before the last part of the path?

ps: I tried to add the path within the () of the PortScanner(), but that hasn't worked neither. (Not even when I used the double \ signs.

Comment: Do you have `nmap` (the program) installed?

Comment: Do you mean a standalone program, or the nmap(without the python-) module? When both the nmap and python-nmap module were installed it gave another different error. Standalone program i haven't tried Edit: the error: AttributeError: module 'nmap' has no attribute 'PortScanner'

Comment: All possible issues with `nmap` have been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71652574/getting-error-attributeerror-module-nmap-has-no-attribute-portscanner/71660197) in details.