# Getting error: AttributeError: module 'nmap' has no attribute 'PortScanner'

Tags: python, module, attributeerror, nmap, port-scanning

I have been seeking for answers of how to fix this Python problem:

> AttributeError: module 'nmap' has no attribute 'PortScanner'

I wanted to learn more about port-scanning but I couldn't even install the module on Visual Studio Code, which I am using.  I've tried everything that I and many people can think of:

1. Uninstalled and reinstalled  python-nmap as well as just nmap (since they are interconnected).
2. I've tried renaming the module itself.
3. I've launched my code on different IDEs
4. I've created a separate folder and put modules and my project there.

No success so far..

This is my code:

```
import nmap


nm = nmap.PortScanner()
nm.scan('127.0.0.1', '22-443')
```

and the output:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users
/user2132/Desktop/PYTHONProjects/portscannning.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user2132/Desktop/PYTHONProjects/portscannning.py", line 3, in <module>
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
AttributeError: module 'nmap' has no attribute 'PortScanner'
```

What can I try next?

P.S. I am using MacOS

Comment: Possible post duplicate (exact title duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992325/attributeerror-module-nmap-has-no-attribute-portscanner

Comment: i've tried, it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error. The problem was with the `nmap` library. `pip install nmap` installs `nmap python library` but `python-nmap` requires `nmap binary`, moreover `nmap` python library conflicts with `python-nmap` because they share same module name. The correct `nmap` could be installed from [Nmap's official download page](https://nmap.org/download.html)

#### Please follow the steps below:

##### Step 1. uninstall libraries

```
pip uninstall nmap
pip uninstall python-nmap
```

##### Step 2. install `python-nmap`

```
pip install python-nmap
```

##### Step 3. Check if `nmap` installed into your system

```
which nmap
```

##### Step 3. If it is installed, continue to the next step, if not:

Go to [Nmap's official download page](https://nmap.org/download.html), download and install nmap for your OS.

Please make sure that `add to PATH` option is selected during installation.

##### Step 4. Reboot your system (restart computer)

Check `nmap` installation with `which nmap` command in terminal.

---

After that you can check if `PortScanner` is in `nmap`.

```
import nmap
dir(nmap)
```

Returns

```
['ET',
 'PortScanner', <=== IS HERE!
 'PortScannerAsync',
 'PortScannerError',
 'PortScannerHostDict',
 'PortScannerTimeout',
 'PortScannerYield',
 'Process',
 '__author__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__last_modification__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 '__version__',
 'convert_nmap_output_to_encoding',
 'csv',
 'io',
 'nmap',
 'os',
 're',
 'shlex',
 'subprocess',
 'sys']
```

Final test

```
import nmap
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
nm.scan('127.0.0.1', '22-443')
```

Returns

```
{'nmap': {'command_line': 'nmap -oX - -p 22-443 -sV 127.0.0.1',
  'scaninfo': {'tcp': {'method': 'syn', 'services': '22-443'}},
  'scanstats': {'timestr': 'Tue Mar 29 15:07:02 2022',
   'elapsed': '7.82',
   'uphosts': '1',
   'downhosts': '0',
   'totalhosts': '1'}},
...
```

Comment: File "/Users/user2132/Desktop/PYTHONProjects/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    nm = nmap.PortScanner()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nmap/nmap.py", line 136, in __init__
    raise PortScannerError(
nmap.nmap.PortScannerError: 'nmap program was not found in path. PATH is : /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin'

Comment: After following your steps, I indeed have the same output with dir(nmap) as you wrote, but the second I run my code, I get this error :(

Comment: After your last edit, something indeed became different, but I was just wandering, is package "wheel" a necessary thing to have installed? I get this:

Collecting python-nmap==0.6.4

Using cached python-nmap-0.6.4.tar.gz (43 kB)

  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done

Using legacy 'setup.py install' for python-nmap, since package 'wheel' is not installed.

Installing collected packages: python-nmap

  Running setup.py install for python-nmap ... done

Successfully installed python-nmap-0.6.4

Comment: it seems like `nmap` conflicts with `python-nmap` because they share the same module name. let me see how it works in my environment

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error. The problem was with the `nmap` library. `pip install nmap` installs the wrong library for `python-nmap`, moreover this `nmap` conflicts with `python-nmap`. The correct `nmap` library must be installed from [Nmap's official download page](https://nmap.org/download.html)

Comment: Downgrade is not required in this case i believe

Comment: man, thank you so much for all your help and your time, but now, after all your four steps, it simply does not launch the code. It's simply blank. 
I've checked my 'which nmap', which returns /usr/local/bin/nmap

Comment: hmm, it seems like `nmap binary` is in place and `python-nmap` has been properly installed. Are you running your code in jupyter notebook or in IDE? I think the issue with blank output is related with environment but not with nmap.

Comment: I’m running my code in Visual Studio Code IDE. Never tried Jupiter notebook

Comment: I hope it helps you [Visual Studio Code is not showing the output of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529153/visual-studio-code-is-not-showing-the-ouput-of-python)

Comment: Yeah, it finally worked!! I am so thankful for all your help, brother!

Answer (score -1):

Try Ctrl+Shift+P, type env, then create a new environment and add `py -3 -m venv .venv` and press Enter.

Comment: I have amended this to include the actual solution, which was given in a comment (answers are permitted to indicate what was wrong, but they must offer a solution to the problem).